# write formatted stuff into file efficiently

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a quite large `vector<string>` in memory, and I want to write each `string` into `./log.txt`, here is how I do it:

```
ofstream ofs("./log.txt");
for (vector<string>::const_iterator cit = vec.begin(); cit != vec.end(); cit++) {
    char buf[30];
    sprintf(buf, "%s\t---@\n", cit->c_str());
    ofs << buf;
}
ofs.close();
```

I'm caring about disk I/O times, is it efficient? Any better I idea?

Comment: You're caring about disk I/O. I'm caring about the blatant buffer overflow danger. Even if this method was faster than `ofs << *cit << " ---@";` I wouldn't do it. As usual the answer for this kind of question is to try both methods (the sane one and the insane one) and time it. YMMV

Comment: I've been reading your comments on the answers you've got. You talk about needing formatting but there is no formatting in the code you've posted. I wonder, are you thinking that sprintf will truncate the string to 30 characters? If so you're mistaken. Just trying to understand what the issue is here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hybrid idea, exploiting the fact that you don't really need to format anything:

```
 for ( /* as you have */ )
 {
     ofs.write(cit->c_str(), cit->size());
     ofs.write("\t---@", 5);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the C detour. Try the obvious

```
ofs << *cit << "\t---@\n";
```

This should be faster than what you currently have. I doubt that any reasonable manual tweaking can make things any faster than what the library will do for you. The reason why the above can be assumed to be faster than your code:

- No parsing of a formatting string
- No copying to a temporary buffer
- No looking for a terminating `'\0'` because a `std::string` will know its length

The last point doesn't apply to the `"\t---@\n"` yet; you could turn that into a `std::string` as well to possibly gain a very little bit of additional performance. There are other reasons why the “pure C++” code is better:

- No danger of buffer overruns
- No problems with `'\0'` characters embedded in your data

Disk I/O should not be a problem, as ofstreams are buffered. So the implementation will gather a number of these strings in memory, before writing them to file all at once. And even then, they will probably be stored in a cache managed by your operating system, to accumulate even larger hunks. So the disk should only see few huge writes, which is pretty efficient.

Comment: @Alcott, I still see no need for formatting. The backslash escapes are part of the string literals and have nothing to do with printf. If you actually do need formatting, you probably should do that with what C++ iostreams provide, but it very much depends on *why* you actually need formatting, i.e. what kind of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is efficient or not depends more on the implementation of ofstream than on your code. This is how it should be. If you need a more efficient ofstream, you can implement one.

However as others have pointed out, your code is unsafe. You should use the C++ stream operators or methods instead.